# Cannot delete a storage account

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I cannot for the life of me delete a storage account created earlier today. The error i'm getting is: Storage account portalvhds09kzndhjw5ncq has container(s) which have an active image and/or disk artifacts. Ensure those artifacts are removed from the image repository before deleting this storage account.

So I've done what all the google search results suggest, which is go to the VM's "tab", click disks and remove any disks (there aren't any), I've also looked at the images page of the storage tab and there's nothing there either. I've got no storage containers, and no blobs.

So I really can't understand why i'm getting the above error and I was hoping someone here might be able to help me.

Happy to provide more information, but I don't know what else to give at this point!

Thanks,

Simon

Answer (score 0):

The container was probably used to house a virtual machine hard drive as blob storage. 
If you just deleted a virtual machine then give it a few minutes for the disks to be deleted. The last time I did it, it took Azure 10-15 minutes to delete the virtual machine and remove all leases.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on waiting, unfortunately i still can't remove the item even now ~24hrs later.

Comment: If you have double checked everything try to delete the storage account using another tool such as [Azure Storage Explorer](http://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Let me know if it helps. I am curious to know what happened.